# "Ignoring exception in on_command_error" when I try to use my error handler with discord.py

Tags: python, error-handling, discord, discord.py

I have added a simple error handler for any commands that have an argument to mention a channel. It will send an error message if you have mentioned an invalid channel. Here is the handler:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.ChannelNotFound):
        await ctx.send('Oops, thats not a channel!')
        return
    raise error
```

but instead of sending an error message, it puts this in the console:

```
Ignoring exception in on_command_error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mmein\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 333, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "pogtato.py", line 39, in on_command_error
    raise error
  File "C:\Users\mmein\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\mmein\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 851, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\mmein\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 786, in prepare
    await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\mmein\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 697, in _parse_arguments
    transformed = await self.transform(ctx, param)
  File "C:\Users\mmein\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 552, in transform
    return await self.do_conversion(ctx, converter, argument, param)
  File "C:\Users\mmein\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 505, in do_conversion
    return await self._actual_conversion(ctx, converter, argument, param)
  File "C:\Users\mmein\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 451, in _actual_conversion
    ret = await instance.convert(ctx, argument)
  File "C:\Users\mmein\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\converter.py", line 321, in convert
    raise ChannelNotFound(argument)
discord.ext.commands.errors.ChannelNotFound: Channel "yes" not found.
```

Heres an example of a command that would raise the error:

```py
@bot.command()
async def chantest(ctx, channel : TextChannel):
    await ctx.send(channel.id)
```

That command just prints out the id of a tagged channel, but should raise the error when I try to use the command without tagging a channel.

I don't know why this is happening, thanks in advance if you help.

Comment: and yes, I tried to mention the channel "yes" which was invalid.

Comment: You are receiving an error because you raised an error, see `raise error`

Comment: either way it gives the same error

Comment: Then update your description with the error where you haven't raised an error.

Comment: it honestly doesnt matter, because your supposed to raise the error in an error handler with on_command_error

Comment: It does matter. `on_command_error` catches the error that is raised in `on_command`. But an error that is raised in `on_command_error` is not caught by `on_command_error`. You are raising an error that will lead to an error.

Comment: @TinNguyen No, he only raises errors that are _not_ `ChannelNotFound` errors. In case his `command` throws one of those, he will enter the if-statement and `return`, so it can't possibly throw that same one again (as it won't be able to reach that part of the code).

Comment: The error is raised by him as evident by the error traceback `File "pogtato.py", line 39, in on_command_error \n raise error` The error traceback which is not raised by him manually is more relevant.

Comment: The way I understand it, I am only raising an error of it is not a ChannelNotFound error. Since removing raise error did not seem to fix anything, and I also tested it on other error handlers that worked and it ruined them, I will not be updating my post.

Comment: Where do you expect this error will raise, in other words, if there is a possibility that this error occurs in which command, would you add that command to your question?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: oooh yeah, I will add that command to my question

Comment: What is your discord.py version and also can you show your imports?

Comment: Its ok, Ive figured out my problem: I had multiple error handlers in different @events, so I had to put it all into one event.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `on_command_error`. Try doing it like this by making the default value of channel is `None.

```py
@bot.command()
async def chantest(ctx, channel : TextChannel=None):
    if not channel:
        await ctx.send('Oops, thats not a channel!')
        return

    await ctx.send(channel.id)
```

Comment: `if not channel:` is better

Comment: Thanks, I figured out a while ago what my problem was, I should have posted it. I had multiple error handlers and I had to put them in 1 event. I will reward the bounty anyway though because this is helpful.